# Up navigation textView empty as back

Tags: android

I have three activity in my application: `ExerciseDaysActivity`, `WorkoutListActivity` and `WorkoutDetailsActivity`.

`WorkoutList` is child of `ExerciseDaysActivity`, and the `WokoutDetailsActivity` is child of `WorkoutListActivity`:

`ExerciseDaysActivtiy` -> `WorkoutListActivity` -> `WorkoutDetailsActivity`

My ExerciseDays activity contains a list of exercises of the week:

```
DAY 1
Chest,Back
DAY 2
. . .
```

etc. Clicking on each record, runs WorkoutList activity, and imparting a string using Intent, shown below:

```
tvMuscleGroup = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.workoutdescr);
String muscle = tvMuscleGroup.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(ExerciseDaysActivity.this, WorkoutListActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mGroup", muscle);
startActivity(intent);
```

WorkoutList activity contains a list of exercises for a particular muscle group, and on top of Layout is the TextView to show a group of muscles that I picked up using getIntent method (in my WorkoutList activity):

```
tvMtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
Intent i = getIntent();
String muscleGroup = i.getStringExtra("mGroup");
tvMtitle.setText(muscleGroup);
```

Clicking on each exercise opens activity with details about each exercise-WorkoutDetailsActivity. 
**My problem** is that when I go back with the Up navigation, (WorkoutDetailsActivity -> WorkoutListActivity), my TextView is empty, but it should not be?
For the first time, after it starts WorkoutListActivity the text in TextView appear, but after I get back with the Up navigation, TextView is empty? I tried to override onResume method, in my WorkoutListActivity and, when I go back from WorkoutDetailsActivitiy to WorkoutList activity, string muscleGroup is null, but it should not be (Should be 'Chest,Back'):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("MY TAG", "value " + muscleGroup);
}
```

When I use classic 'Back' button on my Android phone, everything is OK. Why?

Comment: I solved the problem: inside the AndroidManifest file, for the parent activity is necessary to add: android:launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: Please post this as answer